# Windows 10 recovery only works in UEFI

Tags: windows-10, boot, laptop, uefi, bootable-media

I can't boot into Windows 10 anymore.

I created a USB Recovery disk, however the recovery-disk only boots up in UEFI-mode, but my Windows-SSD (that I want to recover) is only being recognized in "Legacy" mode.

When I boot from the recovery disk in Legacy mode, I only get a blue blank screen. Nothing happens after that. When I press the ENTER key, then the blue screen changes to the windows-logo for about 30 seconds - and it reverts back to the blue blank screen again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I would try is to recreate the recovery drive with Rufus specifying MBR for BIOS or UEFI unless you think it is a GPT, then use GPT for UEFI.
A recovery drive made on another system for Windows 10 will most likely work.
The key is the boot record/file system.